# A simple problem that occupies too much time

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to get Mathematica to solve the following system, consisting of two identical equations, except that the variables z1, u1, u3 (in the first) and zz1, uu1, uu3 (in the second) represent different known numbers.

```
eq1 = z1 - 1/2*(u1 + s1 + Sqrt[s1^2 + u1^2 - 2*u1*s1*(Cos[s2 - u3])]) == 0;
eq2 = zz1 - 1/2*(uu1 + s1 + Sqrt[s1^2 + uu1^2 - 2*uu1*s1*(Cos[s2 - uu3])]) == 0;
Reduce[{eq1, eq2}, {s1, s2}, Reals]
```

He has been running for about an hour without giving me answers.
I solved it by hand and it can be reduced to a second degree equation in $ \cos (s_2) $, so the solutions actually exist.

Is there any error in my setting the problem in the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little help you can solve it.

First Eliminate `s1`

```
eq=Eliminate[{eq1,eq2},s1]
(*z1^2 (-uu1 + 2 zz1 - uu1 Cos[s2 - uu3]) +z1 (u1 uu1 - 2 u1 zz1 + 2 uu1 zz1 - 2 zz1^2 +u1 uu1 Cos[s2 - uu3]) ==u1 zz1 (uu1 - zz1 + uu1 Cos[s2 - u3] - zz1 Cos[s2 - u3])*)
```

The unknown solution `s2` of this equation has 2Pi periodic. [`Weierstrass substitution`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) `s2->2 ArcTan[us2]` evaluates two solutions for `s2`

```
Solve[eq /. s2 -> 2 ArcTan[us2] // TrigExpand, us2] ;
ergs2 = Map[s2 -> # &, 2 ArcTan[us2] /. %]
(*{s2->…,s2->…}*)
```

Comment: Thank you! What's the idea behind this particular substitution used?

Comment: The Weierstrass substitution transforms `Cos[], Sin[],...` into rational expressions, solution becomes easier .